# Running llama-2-13b resulted in Killed

Tags: python, llama

This is my run.py code:

```
import torch
import transformers
import requests
print(torch.cuda.is_available())
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
# Load model and adapter weights from local directory
model = transformers.AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("/home/maxloo/src/pastoring/llama/llama-2-13b")
model.to(device)
adapter = transformers.AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("/home/maxloo/src/pastoring/adapter", config=transformers.configuration.AdapterConfig.from_json_file("adapter_config.json"))
model.load_state_dict(adapter.state_dict())
adapter.load_state_dict(model.state_dict())
# Define prompt
prompt = "Hello, I am a chatbot."
# Perform inference
response = model.generate(prompt, max_length=50)
# Print response
print(response)
```

This is my adapter_config.json code:

```
{
  "base_model_name_or_path": "../llama/llama-2-13b/",
  "bias": "none",
  "enable_lora": null,
  "fan_in_fan_out": false,
  "inference_mode": true,
  "init_lora_weights": true,
  "lora_alpha": 16,
  "lora_dropout": 0.05,
  "merge_weights": false,
  "modules_to_save": null,
  "peft_type": "LORA",
  "r": 16,
  "target_modules": [
    "q_proj",
    "k_proj",
    "v_proj",
    "o_proj"
  ],
  "task_type": "CAUSAL_LM",
  "task": "question_answering",
  "domain": "general"
}
```

These are my hardware specs:

```
Intel Core i7-13700HX, NVIDIA RTX 4060, 32GB DDR5, 1TB SSD
```

I'm using Windows 11 WSL2 Bash to run this command:

```
python3 run.py
```

I expect a chat message to be displayed and a prompt for my chat input, but this is the actual output:

```
Killed
```

How do I resolve this?